# hii community i want to communicate independent lwc in same screen inside flow without using window.postmessage() please help with example

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow

lwc1

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class sendAddressForId extends LightningElement {
    @api TypeAddress;

    handleinput(event){
        console.log(':handleinput:');
        this.TypeAddress=event.target.value;
        console.log(':this.TypeAddress:',this.TypeAddress);
    }

    sendtolwc2(){
        console.log(':sendtolwc2:');
        console.log(':this.TypeAddress:',this.TypeAddress);
        window.postMessage({address:this.TypeAddress, source:'firstlwc'});
    }

}
```

Comment: Either use [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel) _or_ because you're using a Flow, it may also be possible to use [Flow events and properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_flow_screens) on your LWCs that are bound to Flow variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lightning Message Service.

Kindly go through the Salesforce documentation for Lightning Message Service.

Edit: Removed link from answer

Comment: Hi, there's a dislike of link-based answers on this community. It's fine today, but in a month or a few years that link won't work any more. You should ensure you provide a bit more detail directly in your answer to make sure it provides value even when that link stops working.

Comment: This could possibly also be done with Dynamic Interactions (a feature added last year), though not sure if it is supported in screen flows.